# How to add contacts on FireChat?

Tags: applications

I just downloaded [FireChat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FireChat) for my Android. I see it identify you with your email address by making you sign up, but I can't see anyway to add contact on FireChat. Does anyone know how I can add contact on FireChat?

Comment: Firechat by it's design doesn't have contacts as I understand. It's open to all and users hashtags for charts - though you can send private encrypted messages

Comment: @beeshyams - Thanks for reply, so I can send private message only after I have seen that user on public chat, right?

Comment: That's what I  understand from description. Haven't used

Comment: That's what I gather from help /FAQ on internet

Comment: You can figure out and self answer :)

Comment: @beeshyams Thanks, I appreciate your help :) But currently I can't find any use for this app :D